# Unexpected behavior when changing a character in a string in Ruby

Tags: ruby

This code (in Ruby 1.9)

```
word = 'atf'
new_word = word
word[0] = 'w'
puts new_word
```

gives the response "wtf", this

```
word = 'ok'
new_word = word
word = 'wft'
puts new_word
```

gives the response "ok" which is much more what I'd expect. Is this a bug in Ruby or am I wrong in my expectation that changing word, however I change it, shouldn't change new_word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first example, there is only one actual string object, and you have two variable names that refer to it.  Modifying the string therefore modifies each variable.  You could instead do:

```
new_word = word.dup
```

to make a copy.

Comment: Great; so in the second example I reassign the variable name word to a new string object, while leaving new_word assigned to the original string object whereas in the first example I change the string object?

Answer (score 1):

`word[0] = 'w'` is a method call on an object referenced by `word` variable.

`word = 'wft'` is variable assignment.

Answer (score 1):

As said in the other answers you are pointing to variables to the same string object.

''Please remmber'': Ruby never copies/duplicates an object just by assigning it (or returning, or passing to a function). So if you are coming from C/C++, Ruby only works with references/pointers. (And if you are coming from Java: the behavior is very similar to Java non-primitives).

for example:

```
a = [1, 2]
b = a
b << 3
puts a.inspect
# prints [1, 2, 3]
```

or even more confusing if you are not used to it:

```
def foo(x)
  x << 3 
  return nil
end

a = [1, 2]
foo(a)
foo(a)
puts a.inspect
# prints [1, 2, 3, 3]
```

In some cases Ruby provides two methods of the same functionality, one which changes the actual object, the other returns a new object containing the changes.

For example `String#gsub(from, to)` returns a new String containing these changes, on the other hand String#gsub!(from, to)`changes the string itself. Another example would be`Array#reject`vs.`Array#reject!`

`Object#dup` copies an object (but not its nesting objects).

Please note: in most cases not modifying a String is considered good style

Answer (score 0):

The important thing to note is the meaning of:

```
new_word = word
```

The assignment does **not** copy the *value of* `word` into `new_word`. It sets makes the variable `new_word` point to the **same memory address** as the variable `word`.

Therefore, `new_word[0] = 'x'` and `word[0] = 'x'` will have the same effect on the **value of** both variables `new_word` and `word`.

You can fix the problem by doing either:

```
new_word = word.dup
```

or

```
new_word = word.clone
```

`clone` and `dup` create **copies** in memory of the **value of** the variable, and return a reference to that memory, which is then assigned to `new_word`. There are differences between `clone` and `dup` but they're beyond the scope of your question.

Additionally, you will find that many languages function in this way. For instance, you can try the same semantics in C# or javascript, and see the same behavior.